# How do I setInterval with CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

My JavaScript is as follows:

```
var util = require('util');
EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var Ticker = function() {
      var self = this;
      setInterval( function() {
        self.emit('tick');
      }, 1000 );
    }
```

What's the equivalent CoffeeScript?

Comment: Let me clarify... I don't know how to pass 2 arguments to a function with CoffeeScript.

Comment: don't know why this has been downvoted, and someone wants to close it, seems like a valid question to me...

Comment: +1 for reminding me how great CoffeeScript is - I have never actually used it on a project yet, but I think I want to... soon!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
util = require 'util'

EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter

Ticker = ->
  self = this
  setInterval ->
    self.emit 'tick'
  , 1000
  true
```

You add the second parameter by lining up the comma with the function you are passing to, so it knows a second parameter is coming.

It also returns true instead of setInterval, although I can't personally see the advantage of *not* returning the setInterval.

---

Here is a version with thick arrow (see comments), and destructuring assignment (see other comment). Also, returning the setInterval instead of explicitly returning true.

```
util = require 'util'

{EventEmitter} = require 'events'

Ticker = ->
  setInterval =>
    @emit 'tick'
  , 1000
```

Comment: How do I get CoffeeScript to not `return`

    return setInterval(function() {
      return self.emit('tick');
    }, 1000);

Comment: it returns the last thing in the function by default, which is never a bad thing. If you want to avoid returning the setInterval, just put something else at the end, like `true` for example, just underneath the comma in my code.

Comment: Instead of using `self = this`, you can use the "fat arrow" like `setInterval =>` to bind the outer value of `this` to the inner function. ([Demo](http://jeremybanks.github.com/coffee-script/#src:util%20%3D%20require%20'util'%0A%0AEventEmitter%20%3D%20require('events').EventEmitter%0A%0ATicker%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%20%20setInterval%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20self.emit%20'tick'%0A%20%20%2C%201000))

Comment: would you then have to change `self.emit 'tick'` to `this.emit 'tick'`?

Comment: @BillyMoon: Yeah, I love it. You could even put it on one line as `setInterval (=> @emit 'tick'), 1000`

Comment: Totaly unrelated to the question, but: import can be replaced like so: 
`{EventEmitter} = require 'events'`